# jquery sortable on a specific area

Tags: jquery

How do I set the $().sortable(); to a specific area to drag the entire object on? For instance, i want the user to only drag the object by holding on the  area of the object.

this is my JS:

```
$('ul.droptrue').sortable({
            connectWith: 'ul'
});
```

here's my html

```
<ul class="droptrue">
   <li>
       <span>Title</span>
       <div>Body</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$('ul.droptrue').sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul',
    handle: 'span'
});
```

You should read the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-handle).